# Cite all entries in a bib file

Tags: bibtex, citing

I have two `bib` files with references.

I want to do an inline cite of all the references in the second file, but not in the first one.

Is there a way to do so that does not require typing all the references in the second file?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

1. Assign a label to the resource you entered as follows

   `\addbibresource[label=<identifier>]{<name of bibliography file>.bib}`
2. `biblatex` treats the file as a source of bibliographic entries. When, however, you want to cite all references from this file, use

%code

```
\begin{refsection}[<identifier>]

    \nocite{*}

    \printbibliography

\end{refsection}
```

Thus, you tell `biblatex` that it is desired to print the only the references provided from the source file that has a label identified as `<identifier>`

```
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.bib}
@ARTICLE{makram1988a,
    title={{A generalized computer technique for the development of the three-phase impedance matrix for unbalanced power systems}},
    author={Makram, Elham B and Girgis, Adly A},
    journal={Electric power systems research},
    volume={15},
    number={1},
    pages={41--50},
    year={1988},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}
@ARTICLE{makram1989a,
    title={{Development of a three-phase bus impedance matrix in the complex frequency domain for transient analysis in unbalanced distribution systems}},
    author={Makram, Elham and Girgis, Adly},
    journal={Electric Power Systems Research},
    volume={16},
    number={3},
    pages={183--193},
    year={1989},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{makram1989b,
    title={Selection of lines to be switched to eliminate overloaded lines using a Z-matrix method},
    author={Makram, Elham B and Thorton, Katherine P and Brown, Homer E},
    journal={IEEE Transactions on Power Systems},
    volume={4},
    number={2},
    pages={653--661},
    year={1989},
    publisher={IEEE}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{filecontents*}{sampleX.bib}
@article{aldaoudeyeh2016X,
    title={{Photovoltaic-battery scheme to enhance PV array characteristics in partial shading conditions}},
    author={Aldaoudeyeh, Al-Motasem},
    journal={IET Renewable Power Generation},
    volume={10},
    number={1},
    pages={108--115},
    year={2016},
    publisher={IET}
}
@ARTICLE{wu2017X,
    title={{Assessing Impact of Renewable Energy Integration on System Strength Using Site-Dependent Short Circuit Ratio}},
    author={Wu, Di and Li, Gangan and Javadi, Milad and Malyscheff, Alexander M and Hong, Mingguo and Jiang, John Ning},
    journal={IEEE Transactions on Sustainable Energy},
    year={2017},
    publisher={IEEE}
}
@article{wu2019methodX,
    title={A method to identify weak points of interconnection of renewable energy resources},
    author={Wu, Di and Aldaoudeyeh, Al~Motasem and Javadi, Milad and Ma, Feng and Tan, Jin and Jiang, John N and others},
    journal={International Journal of Electrical Power \& Energy Systems},
    volume={110},
    pages={72--82},
    year={2019},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{book}

% BEGIN_FOLD
    \usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}

    \addbibresource{sample.bib}
    \addbibresource[label=special]{sampleX.bib}

    \bibsetup{}

% END_FOLD

\begin{document}

\begin{refsection}[special]

    To cite all sources in a given bibliography file, use \verb|\nocite{*}| command

    \nocite{*}

    \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]

\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

When trying to check the sample code given above, remember to remove the file `.bbl` for each new run

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. One way is by using [JabRef](https://www.jabref.org/) bib manager. Open the second bib file which you want to cite all with JabRef, select all entries, then press push tex citation icon up right. An inline citation for all entries will be pasted in your tex file editor (e.g. Texstudio) in place where you last left the cursor.

Make sure that your latex editor is set properly in JabRef.

[image]